# How to add an Ant Design TabPane at the end of the header

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to use the Ant Design Tab component, and want I want to have 2 TabPane on the left, and then a last TabPane at the end on the right.

[image: Ant design tab component]

It should look like this picture but the "Extra Action" should be another TabPane.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: I would check out `renderTabBar` prop, or doing it with css

Comment: @alextrastero I think the renderTabBar would affect all the Tabs in the TabPane, doing it with CSS seems to be the only thing we can do I think

Comment: Yeah I think doing it withh CSS makes the most sense, but I'm not entire sure how you'd do it with CSS.